For index option pricing which model should be used black 76 or black scholes
For index option pricing -
Which model should be used black 76 or black scholes.
Please provide me pros and cons.

For options on index futures (such as are traded on the CME) black 76, for options on the index (such as are traded on the CBOE) black scholes. For options on SPY shares, also black scholes.

Black 76 for options on index futures and Black-Scholes on index options like SPX options. Reasons and assumptions are covered extensively in Hull. See also sections on bond options, swaptions, etc.
For options on index futures, quick way to cross-check this is to compare your implementation against CME QuikStrike, which is free to access. Example implementation here.
